# Select ReplaySubject values emitted untill now

Tags: javascript, rxjs, subject, replaysubject

Is there reliable solution to get a snapshot of values currently buffered in ReplaySubject?

I came up with something like this, but not sure how reliable this solution is:

```
replaySubject.pipe(
    takeUntil(timer(10).pipe(take(1)))
)
```

The timer factor above seems wrong to me as I have no warranty if all values have been emitted properly within given time (this applies to replay subjects with a lot of values).

Comment: AFAIK, the `ReplaySubject` emits all the buffered values at once, in an array. Wouldn't `subj.pipe(take(1))` be enough?

Comment: Nope, it would just re-emit the first value from the buffer - you can check out this https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bidpjt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be an approach:

```js
replay
  .pipe(
    buffer(timer(0)),
    take(1)
  )
  .subscribe(a => {
    console.log(`This is one time value ${a}`);
  });
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zxjuue).

The `ReplaySubject`, when a new subscriber is registered, it will emit [its values synchronously](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/ReplaySubject.ts#L79-L81):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < copy.length && !subscriber.closed; i += infiniteTimeWindow ? 1 : 2) {
      subscriber.next(copy[i] as T);
    }
```

for this reason, we're using `buffer(timer(0))`: by the time the `buffer`'s notifier(`timer(0)`) emits, the values will have already been added in the `buffer`'s array. So, it will be able to emit all the `ReplaySubject`'s accumulated values.

Comment: Nicely spotted the synchronous emition of buffered values. Too bad there isn't some kind of length of buffer on replay subject also. Anyway. Thank you for your input! :)